# All apps deleted

Tags: applications, battery, reboot, delete, tecno-n3

Please help, I was trying to power on my Android phone, it took longer time than usual but when it eventually Powers on all my third party apps had been deleted but my files are still intact, what caused this and can I recover my phone back?

Comment: Backup. Backup everything. What if you lose your phone? That no one can recover. There are a lot of apps for that. Probably you can not recover your data, because rooting it deletes everything. There is a little chance that there is some loophole what you make an answer for you, but don't have too much hope.

Comment: But how can I back up some app data for example I have 7gb of courses i downloaded on pluralsight app for offline use and I can't see the files on my phone storage

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have booted up in SAFEmode on your Android device. When you boot into SAFEmode all 3rd party apps are organically disabled to allow for more accurate troubleshooting of the device. You will know that you are in SAFEmode by looking at the bottom left corner of the device, If it reads SAFEmode than that would be your issue. In the event that is not the issue please let me know

Comment: Safe mode is not the case because there's no safe mode displayed and I even tried later and was able to put the phone on safe mode and back to the normal State but the problem persists